# Orthant integral of non centred gaussian

Tags: integration

I am having hard time to figure out if there is a way to get a close-form of the following integral:
$$\int\limits_0^{ + \infty } {{{\left( {\frac{1}{{{\sigma ^2}}}} \right)}^{N + 3}}\exp \left\{ { - \frac{1}{{2{\sigma ^2}}}{Y^T}\left[ {I - {R^{ - 1}}} \right]Y + \frac{1}{\sigma }{Y^T}{R^{ - 1}}\xi } \right\}d} \sigma 
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbeqaaeaacaGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaa8qCaeaada
% qadaqaamaalaaabaGaaGymaaqaaiabeo8aZnaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOm
% aaaaaaaakiaawIcacaGLPaaadaahaaWcbeqaaiaad6eacqGHRaWkca
% aIZaaaaOGaciyzaiaacIhacaGGWbWaaiWaaeaacqGHsisldaWcaaqa
% aiaaigdaaeaacaaIYaGaeq4Wdm3aaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaaaaki
% aadMfadaahaaWcbeqaaiaadsfaaaGcdaWadaqaaiaadMeacqGHsisl
% caWGsbWaaWbaaSqabeaacqGHsislcaaIXaaaaaGccaGLBbGaayzxaa
% GaamywaiabgUcaRmaalaaabaGaaGymaaqaaiabeo8aZbaacaWGzbWa
% aWbaaSqabeaacaWGubaaaOGaamOuamaaCaaaleqabaGaeyOeI0IaaG
% ymaaaakiabe67a4bGaay5Eaiaaw2haaiaadsgaaSqaaiaaicdaaeaa
% cqGHRaWkcqGHEisPa0Gaey4kIipakiabeo8aZbaa!630E!
$$

R : N*N SDP Matrix.

I: Identity Matrix.

Y : N*1 vector .

ξ : N*1 vector.

Thank you for your answers and guidance.

Comment: Avoid using constants with a complex expression, they just add clutter.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, with $u:=\dfrac1\sigma$, the integral is of the form

$$\int_0^\infty u^{n+1}e^{-au^2/2+bu}du.$$

Then by a linear change of variable and assuming $a>0$, you turn it to

$$\int_0^\infty\left(v-c\right)^{n+1}e^{-v^2/2}dv.$$

By the Binomial theorem, this is a sum of the $k^{th}$ order moments of the Gaussian, for which formulas are available (or can be retrieved by integration by parts).

---

**Update:**

My bad, after the change of variable, the lower bound is no more $0$, so that the integrals require the incomplete Beta function (or the Error function). So there is no hope of a closed-form without special functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Yves Daoust I made that variable change and get a similar formula but the lower side of the integral is not zero but $$\frac{b}{{\sqrt a }}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbeqaaeaacaGaaiaabaqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaaSaaaeaaca
% WGIbaabaWaaOaaaeaacaWGHbaaleqaaaaaaaa!37EA!
$$ which make thing more complicated

Comment: @AyoubSbitti: ooops, right.

Comment: My original problem arise from a probabilistic calculation of posterior probability distribution of hyperparameters.this hyperparameters  have to be integrated or maximized to get de MAP (Maximum a Posteriori)  of that hyperparameters